# 'jpaMappingContext' bean initialization is slow

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

My web app takes very long to startup ~ 180 secs - analysis shows that entityManagerFactory bean creation takes around 80 secs while creating the jpaMappingContext bean is around 90 secs. I got this by turning on logging for 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory'.
I have around 500 entities. Spring version is 4.3.11.RELEASE - spring-data ver is 1.9.4.RELEASE, hibernate version is 4.3.11.Final.

Any suggestions on how to speed up boot time - especially jpaMappingContext.

thx
-anish

Comment: 500 entities seems quite a large number; are they all necessary?

Comment: unfortunately yes - its a pretty large financial app